# I want to implement checkbox within a toolbar menu, and Check box shows but does not tick, any ideas?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-actionbar

I am making an app, where the toolbar has a menu, and within has 2-3 checkboxes.I have code put down for xml and java, and checkbox displays. But nothing gets ticked when i press. Code below

action_bar xml which gets included in main activity :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/eleaf"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:checked="false"
    android:orderInCategory="5"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:title="E-Leaf"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:onClick="itemClicked"/>
```

Java for onOptionsItemsSelected :

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    boolean checked = item.isChecked();

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.eleaf:
            if(checked){
                Toast.makeText(this, "E-Leaf Map shown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                item.setChecked(false);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.biomass:
            if (checked){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Biomass Map shown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                item.setChecked(false);
            }
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I had this line in oncreate but not really using it :

```
    CheckBox checkEleaf = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.eleaf);
```

Any suggestions on how to go about this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Within each case in your switch you have to return true.

Answer (score 0):

You have this code in your 1st case :

```
 case R.id.eleaf:
            if(checked){
                Toast.makeText(this, "E-Leaf Map shown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                item.setChecked(false);
            }
            break;
```

In this you are calling `setChecked(false)` only when its already check by `if(checked)` condition.. you should change this code to following code :

```
 case R.id.eleaf:

                    if (checked) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "E-Leaf Map shown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked()); // this will make check,uncheck
                    break;
```

Comment: thanks ...when i press the check box, it shows me this in android monitor : E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null